# import data with Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The issue I have is with importing nodes from a CSV file into Neo4J database

The code is:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "File:///shakespear/Author.csv" AS Line
CREATE (:Author {Id: Line.Id, firstname: Line.firstname, lastname: Line.lastname})
```

The csv file is:

```
Id, firstname, lastname
1, "William", "Shakespear"
2, "Francis", "Bacon"
```

I got 2 nodes 
{"Id":"1"}
{"Id":"2"}

But it doesn't give me the first- and lastname in the node.
How do I get these two properties in my nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSV file cannot have any extraneous whitespace.

This content should work:

```
Id,firstname,lastname
1,"William","Shakespear"
2,"Francis","Bacon"
```

also this:

```
Id,firstname,lastname
1,William,Shakespear
2,Francis,Bacon
```

Also, if you intend the `Author` nodes' `Id` properties to have integer values, then your Cypher code should use `TOINTEGER(Line.Id)` instead of `Line.Id`.